# Modifying the build-in site columns ,, should this always be avoided

Tags: 2013, content-type, administration, site-column

I have a team site collection inside SharePoint server 2013. Now I added a new issue tracking list, where the build-in site columns such as priority, status, description,comments,assigned to etc satisfy most of my needs. But I want to have these two modifications to the build-in site columns:-

- The build-in site column named “priority” came with a default value = `(2) Normal` While in my case I want to remove the default value of the priority. I know I can do this at the list level, but I do not want to have the site column and its list copy not in sync. So my question is it a bad practice to remove the default value of the built-in Priority site column ? and it is better to create a new site column similar to the built-in Priority but without default value ?
- Another modification I want to do it that the built-in Description field is set as optional with “Rich Text editor”, while I want to make it a “Required” with “Enhanced rich text editor”. So  I am asking the same question is it bad to modify the built-in Description site column and do these 2 modifications ? or it is better to create a new site column similar to the Description that is defined as required with Enhanced rich text ?
  Thanks

Comment: You can create a content type and make modifications to that content type. This ensures the modifications stay within the content type.

Comment: this is not 100% correct, you can not modify the defualt value from the CT level,, this need to be done to the site column itself !! inside the CT you can specify if the column is hidden, reuired, optional... but you can not chnage it from "rich text" to "enhanced rich text" or it clear its defualt value..

Comment: You're right. My bad. As for your question, since you mentioned you don't like having the site column and list column not in sync, a better practice would be to create different site columns to avoid syncing with other lists which use the same site column.